# Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use the below function to find values in form fields, The reason its loops is because the form changes dynamically which means there could be gaps in the ID of the field

Java script function is

```
function totalProductPrice() {
        var maxid = document.getElementById("field_id").value;
        var i = 0;
        var totalprice = 0;

        while (i<=maxid)
            {
                totalprice += document.getElementById("QuoteItem" + i + "price").value;
                i++;
            }

        document.getElementById("QuoteTotalcost").value = totalprice;
    }
```

and then on one of the input fields i have

```
onchange='totalProductPrice();'
```

When i change the value of this field it should add up all the fields and then insert it into the field called QUoteTotalcost but when i try it does nothing, In the console of firebug it outputs

```
element.dispatchEvent is not a function
[Break on this error] element.dispatchEvent(event);
prototype.js (line 4619)
document.getElementById("QuoteItem" + i + "price") is null
[Break on this error] totalprice += document.getElementById("QuoteItem" + i + "price").value;
```

Comment: the id seems invalid from the firebug errors. are you sure you have elements with ids as "QuoteItem1price", "QuoteItem2price", etc.. and did you check the case sensitivity?

Comment: Yeah i checked it over and over just ot make sure i wasnt going crazy..the  id does vary according to what has been created and deleted - ie in some cases the first valid one will be QuoteItem4price so it should be able to skip through those first 3 without any issues i would imagine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does that because you're trying to read a property on a null object. You need to check if the object exists.

```
while (i <= maxid) {
  var item = document.getElementById("QuoteItem" + i + "price");
  if (item != null) {
    totalprice += parseFloat(item.value);
  }
}
```

That's a somewhat crude way of adding up totals though. Its usually better to use classes for this kind of thing:

```
<input type="text" class="quote-item-price">
```

with:

```
var items = document.getElementByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].className == "quote-item-price") {
    totalprice += parseFloat(items[i].value);
  }
}
```

That way you don't have to mess around with IDs to make sure they're unique, etc.

**Edit:** You've tagged your question with jQuery. With jQuery it's much much simpler.

```
var totalprice = 0;
$("input.quote-item-price").each(function() {
  totalprice += parseFloat($(this).val());
  // or
  totalprice += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

**Edit 2:** form field values are strings. If you use `+` with them it is a string concatenation. I've modified the above to call [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseFloat) to convert any values to numbers. You may need to convert that to a fixed number of decimal places using [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToFixed):

```
totalprice = totalprice.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thank its resolved the errors and its now being passed to the totalprice field but insead of adding teh values together its just appending it onto the previous one, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for that - Sorry i didnt realise the difference coming from PHP where it works it all out for you, Cheers :D